# Phalcon DevTools: Unable to create project directory. Mkdir() permission denied

Tags: xampp, phalcon

I'm a beginner in working with PHP frameworks. Yesterday I tried to create a project with the Phalcon Developer Tools but I get the following error message:

> PHP Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in D:\xampp\phalcon-tools\scripts\Phalcon\Builder\Project.php on line 102
>
> Error: Unable create project directory C:\Windows\System32\tutorial

Does this have something to do with my project directory path? I couldn't find any answers to my question so I hope someone can help me here. I'm using the XAMPP development environment. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by going to the right disk in my CMD (:D). After that I searched for the directory xampp\htdocs and then created my project with the command: phalcon create-project tutorial.

[image]